# How to set integration limits

Tags: numerical-integration, regions

Consider the functions

```
cosa[ts_,th_,ph_]=Cos[ph]*Sin[th]*Sin[ts]+Cos[th]*Cos[ts];
Aa[gh_] = gh;
Bb[gh_,ms_]=Sqrt[gh^2-1]/(gh*Sqrt[1-4*ms^2/125^2]);
cosacrittemp[gh_,ms_]=x /. Solve[A^2*(B^2 - 1)*(x^2 - 1) + x^2 == 0, x]/.{A->Aa[gh],B->Bb[gh,ms]}
cosacritmax[gh_,ms_]=If[Bb[gh,ms]>=1,Abs[cosacrittemp[gh,ms][[1]]],1]
cosacritmin[gh_,ms_]=If[Bb[gh,ms]>=1,-Abs[cosacrittemp[gh,ms][[1]]],-1]
```

Here the variables are defined in domains
$$
0<ms<62.5, \quad 0<ts<\pi, \quad 0 < ph < 2\pi, \quad 1 < gh < 35
$$ 
I need to perform some integral
$$
g(ts,ms)=\int \limits_{1}^{35}dgh \int dth \int dph\ f(ts,ms,gh,th,ph),
$$
where the integration domain for `th` and `ph` is set by

```
cosa[ts,th,ph]-cosacritmax[gh,ms]<0 && cosa[ts,th,ph]-cosacritmin[gh,ms]<0
```

How to set it in Mathematica?

Comment: Try: `dom=ImplicitRegion[(cosa[ts,th,ph]-cosacritmax[gh,ms]<0) && (cosa[ts,th,ph]-cosacritmin[gh,ms]<0), {th,ph}]; Integrate[yourfun, Element[{th,ph},dom]]`

Comment: Please define values for `gh`, `ms`, `ts` so that people can suggest working solutions.

Comment: @Roman : thank you for the suggestion, I have updated my question.